# Given connected $(X,O)$ space , $\emptyset \ne A \subseteq X$ and $\partial(A)=\emptyset$: Show, $A = X$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Given connected $(X,O)$ topological space , $\emptyset \ne A \subseteq X$ and $\partial(A)=\emptyset$: Show, $A = X$

Well, my idea:

$\emptyset$ = $\partial(A)$ = $\overline A \setminus A°$, which implies, that $\overline A = \emptyset$ or $\overline A = A°$.
In case $\overline A = A°$, we can conclude, that $A=\overline A = A°$ because of $A° \subseteq A \subseteq \overline A$. That reveals that A is open and closed (since $A°$ is open and $\overline A$ is closed), which shows by definition ($X$ is connected <=> $A = X$, if $\emptyset \ne A \subseteq X$ is open and closed), that $A = X$ holds.

In case $\overline A = \emptyset$, we have that $A$ = $\emptyset$, because of $A \subseteq \overline A$. But we said, that $A \ne \emptyset$. That means, that this case is not going to happen anyway, so we are done.

Is my solution correct? Or is there something I missed/ have done wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: In any space $X,$ and any $A\subseteq X,$ the trio $A^o, \partial A, (A^c)^o=(X\setminus A)^o$ are pair-wise disjoint and the union of the trio is $X.$

Comment: Should that be also a solution/hint to that problem? Because I don't see, what I gain from that...